# VrVideoView play normal video

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

`YouTube` already has such function "play in `CardBoard`" which will reformat the footage to make it feel like you are watching in an Imax theatre.

How to do it with android `VR` Sdk. i'm takeing look at `VrVideoView`. When playing an normal video, It generate very strange view point for the normal `2D` video and play it as `3D` video.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The VrVideoView only renders the video in a 360° way and it gives an awfull result if the video is not a 360° video.

So you have to use a GvrView and manage the renderring youself in order to have a good result.

Here's a quick and dirty example about how to display a stereoscopic video with the Google VR SDK

https://github.com/Zanfas/Cardboard_VideoPlayer

You have to know that the Google VR SDK only apply distorsion to the rendering of a 3D Scene managed with Open GL ES.

The idea is to make a virtual screen in a 3D scene that displays the video. You render the 3D scene with the camera looking at that screen and there you go.

Regards